# Software testing workflow using TFS

Tags: testing, tfs, manual-testing

I'm a software tester at a medium-sized company developing software for a machine (not web or pure desktop applications). Previously my task was quite simple: Just preparing a test plan and test cases in a document, then carrying out all those tests manually. During my testing I am only concerned about the performance/interaction of the machine.

A couple of months ago, our division introduced TFS, and I'm learning to integrate my software testing into this new system. So far, what I have done is to simply set up several "not automated" test cases for a pilot project. However, I'm wondering where or how I can record my already conducted tests in TFS. I mean, where or how can I update the results of my tests? Or it is unnecessary to do so? Just add bugs in case of errors?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsoft Test Manager 2010 for writing your test cases and from there you can add the bug id which you have created earlier also to the respective Test Case but for that you require Microsoft Test Manager 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need Visual Studio Test to record executed tests, which you can read about here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/test-professional

I don't think this comes with Team Foundation Server, but does come with Enterprise licenses of Visual Studio or can be purchased separately.

Comment: The product is now called "[Visual Studio Test Professional 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/test-professional)"

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you recommend me any on-line crash tutorial on manual testing with this tool?

Comment: I attended this webinar last month, it focuses more on automation with Visual Studio Test Professional, but does demonstrate features such as defining test cases, executing them and recording them.

https://www.clicktoattend.com/invitation.aspx?code=152816

Comment: Just in case you don't get this in time, here's a schedule of upcoming webinars of the same subject:

https://www.clicktoattend.com/search.aspx?partner=search&range=Next%206%20Months&partnerid=23554&webcast=1&seminar=1&partnername=Northwest Cadence Corporation

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In TFS, you can map each requirement to a Test Plan and plan to test cases and Create Test Runs for different releases and generate Test Report.

Below URL could be helpful to you:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182409.aspx